# How to combine 2 types in TS without creating a 'never' type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

`type a = "a"`

`type bc = "b" | "c"`

`type abc = a & bc`

Hi all - when I run the above snippet to combine types a & bc, `typeof` abc becomes `never`. Is there a way for me to combine a & bc so that `type abc = "a" | "b" | "c"` ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: type abc = a | bc

Answer (score 1):

You'd combine them the same way as you combine the b and c:

```
type a = "a";
type bc = "b" | "c"
type abc = a | bc;
```

---

**What does `&` do then?**

It creates a type consisting of what's common between the joint types. And since there is nothing shared between a and bc, the resulting type is `never`.