# Typescript: Type 'string | boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to get typescript to work for shared value types.
This is the code being used:

```js
type ContextProps = Record<
    "template" | "folder" | "repository" | "projectPath" | "baseName",
    string | null
>;

type InstallDependenciesProps = Record<"installDependencies", boolean | null>;

type CombinedProps = ContextProps & InstallDependenciesProps;

const context: CombinedProps = { template: null, folder: null, repository: null, projectPath: null, baseName: null, installDependencies: false, };

const setValue = (
    key: keyof CombinedProps,
    value: CombinedProps[keyof CombinedProps]
) => {
    context[key] = value;
};
```

But this throws an error for `context[key] = value;`

```bash
Type 'string | boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.
```

I tried using `Partial` and `Optional` on CombinedProps but I got the same error, except it was expecting `never`

Comment: do you mean: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74521879/3462319

Comment: What is `context` defined as?

Comment: Tried it out before, this doesn't seem to work for my problem

Comment: @fredrik const context: CombinedProps = {
 template: null,
 folder: null,
 repository: null,
 projectPath: null,
 baseName: null,
 installDependencies: false,
};

Comment: How about using generics? `const setValue = <K extends keyof CombinedProps> (key: K, value: CombinedProps[K]) => { context[key] = value; };`. But I think there should a duplicate somewhere explaining what happens when `key` is of type `A | B | ...` and you try using `object[key] =...` (using the key in the left side of an assignment). The right side of the assignment is expected to be something like `typeof object[A] & typeof object[B] & ...`. In your case, `string | null` & `boolean | null` is just `null`.

Comment: @qrsngky Looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870887/assert-a-value-type-is-the-same-at-both-sides-of-the-assignment/75879314#75879314)?

Comment: This one is kind of related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57389826/typescript-union-of-type-is-resolved-as-intersection-of-types (settings: strictNullChecks is false) Even though `obj[key]` is usually of type `J | B`  (as `let temp = obj[key]` will show you), writing to it like `obj[key] = ...` expects `J & B`.

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74704514/2887218)?  The original `setValue` is unsafe because it allows `setValue("template", false)`, so you probably want generics anyway.

Comment: @qrsngky Generics was the way to go!
Thanks a lot